# Can we get a timer for ban lift in questions?

Tags: feature-request, quality-filter

I have more good rep than bad I think, but deleted a question(s) any chance we get a timer for ban lift?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th.

Answer (score 2):

Without intending to offend you, your meta post here, and your chat questions make me think you undergo an amnesia from one day to another.

So hear my advise revisit your questions, make them good questions so they are good to answer, accept answers where you got good ones, stop deleting questions, have a positive impact on the site, this isn't done within a day.

Most of us try to answer your questions in chat because we see good intentions. You as well really should read through the links you got provided in chat and in the comment to your question here.

> [What can I do when getting 'we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account'!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

So, this out of the way, like I said, go through your questions, improve them, a good way is to have them the following format and providing those informations within your question:

- Which is the situation you're facing?
- What steps did you try already to solve them?
- What are the error messages you can provide?
- What additional information you can provide?

If your questions you have deleted are not salvageable, then at least make the ones you have good ones, so you gain a positive question reputation and your ban might be lifted in some time. Like I said already in the start this isn't done in a day and **moderators can't impact that in any way**.